# PC Turn on when connected to power without pressing power button

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power

I need some help with my strange behavior of my new PC.
My setup is
AMD Ryzen 5 3500X
MSI B450-A Pro MAX
Colorful igame gtx 1660 super
Klevv bolt-X 2x8 GB
PSU be quiet system power 9 500W

The problem is, when first connected to power. My PC will always turn on by itself without pressing the button.
But if I not disconnect the power source / turn off the PSU (normal shutdown only), next time I can turn on my PC normal with pressing the power.

And "Even If" I disconnect the power source / turn off the PSU "Not more than 5-10 minute". When I connect the power source / turn on PSU, It won't turn on automatically.

But If I disconnect the power source / turn off the PSU "More than 10 minute". When I connect the power source / turn on PSU, It will always turn on automatically.

After so many test try using other PSU / RAM / Processor / Motherboard.
I find when I change the Motherboard, this problem is not happen.

But when I bring this to official MSI support center in my city. They say nothing wrong with their Motherboard and don't find any faulty there.
Can you guys help me what should I do? Or maybe something that i need to do to check my motherboard. Because I'm not an electrician expert, i can't check the mobo myself. Just trial and error.

And lastly even if my motherboard is okay, is this kind of problem gonna hurt my entire setup? Or is it just some small error that can be ignored. Thx before

---

Update

After I talk to the MSI support center again, they show me that when they testing with their processor. The motherboard is okay and not faulty.
They said that the faulty one maybe the processor.

And I goes to AMD, and they test it with their motherboard. And the result is their processor is okay. But when they test it with my motherboard and my processor. The auto on is happen again. So AMD says maybe BIOS problem.

And so i decide to don't care the problem.
But just curiosity, does there ever incompatible motherboard/processor even the socket is okay?

And is there someone have same problem with me using MSI-A PRO MAX / Ryzen 5 3500X

Comment: Is your power button connected to the motherboard with the correct polarity?

Comment: @spikey_richie Buttons don't have polarity, they only connect two wires together when pressed.

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention. In some my testing setup I do it with only connected to PSU - Motherboard -  CPU - CPU Fan - RAM. So no other cable connected and the result is same it will auto boot without jump the power.
So I don't think it because the wires.

Comment: So your set-up is unshielded. May be an external signal affects the mainboard (e.g. a cell phone nearby) and therefore forces your mobo to boot?

Comment: @Robert no, it's completely shielded. It's just in process to find out what's the cause of my problem. I try so many things, and one of them is that setup. Where i only connect psu-mobo-cpu-cpufan-ram so it's easy to try each part.

Comment: Is Wake On "whatever" enabled in BIOS?  Disable all "Wake On..." settings.  I have had this issue before.

Comment: All already disabled.

Comment: Hi, did you solved your problem?

Comment: I want my PC to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Check the [manual](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/mb/E7B86v4.0.pdf), page 47:

> **→ Restore after AC Power Loss [Power Off]**
>
> Sets the system behaviors while encountering the AC power loss.
>
> - `[Power Off]` Leaves the system in power off state after restoring AC power
> - `[Power On]` Boot up the system after restoring AC power.
> - `[Last State]` Restores the system to the previous state (power on/ power off) before AC power loss.

Your current setting seems to be *Power On*. Change it to *Power Off*.

Comment: No, I already check the BIOS. It's Power Off

Comment: toggle the setting to power on, save changes and exit bios, enter bios again and set to to power off, save changes and exit bios, is the behavior the same?.